# "attepted to index nil with Humanoid"

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

```
local animationstomp = script.Animation
local user = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local char = player.Character
local human = char.Humanoid
user.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, proccesedevent)
if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.F then
    local animationtrack = human:LoadAnimation(animationstomp)
    
animationtrack:play()
    end 
    end
end)
```

this script keeps returning error "attempted to index nil with huamnoid" i have looked for solutions on dev forum and on stack overflow but i could not find anything so im going to post myself. anyone catch any erros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"attempted to index nil with huamnoid"
What that means is that this script loaded before the player's character loaded in.

---

To fix this, you can use

```lua
local char = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait() 
-- uses the player if it's already loaded in, or waits for the character to load in
```

Also make sure to use

```lua
local human = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid") 
-- to make sure you wait till the humanoid gets added
```

---

Final script

```lua
local animationstomp = script.Animation
local user = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local char = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local human = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
user.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, proccesedevent)
   if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.F then
        local animationtrack = human:LoadAnimation(animationstomp)
        animationtrack:play()
    end
end)
```